# concurrent UPDATEs in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, sql-update

I have a PHP script that calls the following MySQL query:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1=1
WHERE column1=0
```

The PHP script then returns `mysqli_affected_rows`.

There should be possible to get a positive result only once, since there would be no row with `column1=0` after this script has been executed.

My question is: Would it be theoretically possible to get a positive result more than once if this script is executed many times concurrency?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the database engine used for the table.

If you're using MyISAM, it will lock the whole table while it's performing the query. Other queries that try to access the table will be blocked until it's done. When they run, there will be no rows that match the condition. So only one of them will perform any updates.

If you're using InnoDB, it locks the individual rows that it updates. Different concurrent queries can update different rows of the table, so they'll each get non-zero results.

Comment: I was just kidding, earlier. I'm sorry.