# What if i run 2 or more update queries on the same data in a table simultaneously

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to know whether the queries will be queued to execute one after the other or else how are those queries managed to execute in SQL?

Ex :
Assume a table Users with columns UserID, Name, PhoneNumber, Address

Below are the 2 queries to be executed simultaneously

```
Update Users set Address='abc' where UserID=2

Update Users set Address='xyz' where UserID=2
```

In the above case what will be updated Address? Is it 'abc' or 'xyz'?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concurrent updates to the same row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669189/concurrent-updates-to-the-same-row) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39421294/concurrent-updates-in-mysql or probably many more. I feel this demonstrates a lack of background research before posting. Also, nothing is *actually* simultaneous in computing: every one thing occurs either before or after every other thing. The rest is just a question of how the system deals with things that happen *very close* in time in order to prevent race conditions. A DBMS won't allow those either way.

Comment: I will suggest to go back and read ACID Properties

Comment: It is true that I have no much knowledge about DBMS. Just had a random thought about this scenario.

Comment: As well as looking in to ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability), also look in to `TRANSACTIONS` and then `ISOLATION LEVEL` and/or `LOCKING`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a horse race.  Whichever query the MySQL server handles last is the one that determines the ending value of the column. It *will* handle them sequentially, even if you present them in a way you believe is simultaneous.

There's no such thing as "simultaneous" updates to a row in any [ACID-compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) DBMS.  Large-scale DBMS systems go to an almost unimaginable amount of trouble internally to make sure this is true.

If you had these two queries, on the other hand, you'd get the same end value regardless of the order of their execution.

```
  UPDATE Users SET Count=Count+1 WHERE UserID=2
  UPDATE Users SET Count=Count+2 WHERE UserID=2
```

Comment: `There's no such thing as "simultaneous" updates to a row in any ACID-compliant DBMS` :)

Comment: "There's no such thing as "simultaneous" updates to a row in any ACID-compliant DBMS" you are assuming the topicstarter is using InnoDB as table engine... Besides there are also no  "simultaneous" updates possible if the topicstarter is using MyISAM as table engine.